# Angular not listening to jQuery triggered events and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Angular5@latest here, I have several components that are using several javascript with jQuery plugins and I need them, but when the dom is modified by such plugins angular bindings does not update their values and also vice versa. The same thing happens when the dom is modified by a change in angular variables.

I came up with this rough solution:

```
$('*').each(function()
{
  $(this).on("change",
  (event)=>
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.detail!=="ng")
    {setTimeout(()=>{this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change", {detail: "ng"}));},0);}
  });
});
```

for some reasons events fired using trigger() are only listened in jQuery but events fired using dispatchEvent() are listened by both.

And to do it in reverse I found nothing better than manually trigger specific events like:

```
  jq_update()
  {
    $('.select-chosen').each(function(){setTimeout(()=>{$(this).trigger("chosen:updated", true, true);}, 0)});
    $('.datepicker').each(function(){setTimeout(()=>{$(this).trigger("oninput", true, true);}, 0)});
  }
```

Is there a better solution to these issues? using ChangeDetectorRef and Zone does absolutly nothing and I wonder why...

Comment: Could you please make your question more specific? What jQuery plugin(s) are you trying to use and which of their events are you interested in responding to?

Comment: Basically what i want is to update anguar varibles binded with [(ngModel)] when correspondind dom element is changed by jquery and to trigger jquery events when an angular binded variable is changed. It would be nice also to know why ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() does not work and how to listen to all dom related angular events, thanks